# I need to select one or two fields in middle of filenames with multiple fields, preferably using cut or similar bash command

Tags: bash, cut

I have a directory with lots of files with names like this: *** _ *** _ *** *number*(possibly)v2_ * . * . * _1

I would like to remove everything but "number" and "_v2" (if it's there), preferably using "cut" or a similar command, since I'm somewhat familiar with bash shell scripting, but not with awk e.g.

I've tried using various cut commands, for instance:
To remove first three fields + delimiter "_", I used this:

```
for file in FIRSTSTRING_SECONDSTRING_THIRDSTRING_*; do echo mv $file $(echo $file | cut -c 26-); done
```

And then then I would like to cut away the last two fields. But I don't know how to do that.

Of course, if all filenames had "*number*" in the middle, then I could get rid of the final fields like this:

```
for file in *_1; do echo mv $file $(echo $file | cut -d "_" -f 1); done
```

or like this if all had "_number_v2_":

```
for file in *_1; do echo mv $file $(echo $file | cut -d "_" -f 1,2); done
```

But since there are two kinds of filenames, I don't know how to do this. I could use "rev" and remove the first two fields, then "rev" again, but cut doesn't remove, it selects. Is there a command that removes rather than selects?

Comment: Provide some samples of these filenames

Comment: ABTDWQSDDFFSEWQA_NMDA_PRE_335_20030613.080620.437000_1
ABTDWQSDDFFSEWQA_NMDA_PRE_335_v2_20080129.160957.203000_1
ABTDWQSDDFFSEWQA_NMDA_PRE_336_20030603.170328.281000_1
ABTDWQSDDFFSEWQA_NMDA_PRE_336v2_20080129.160957.203000_1

Comment: And your expected output?

Comment: 335, 
335_v2,
336,
336v2

Comment: @2886045: Ok see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You can use awk:

```
$> cat file
BTDWQSDDFFSEWQA_NMDA_PRE_335_20030613.080620.437000_1
ABTDWQSDDFFSEWQA_NMDA_PRE_335_v2_20080129.160957.203000_1
ABTDWQSDDFFSEWQA_NMDA_PRE_336_20030603.170328.281000_1
ABTDWQSDDFFSEWQA_NMDA_PRE_336v2_20080129.160957.203000_1

$> awk -F_ '$5=="v2"{print $4, $5; next} {print $4}' OFS=_ file
335
335_v2
336
336v2
```

**UPDATE:: To rename all files with above pattern:**

```
cd /somedir
while read l; do
    echo mv "$l" "$(awk -F_ '$5=="v2"{print $4, $5; next} {print $4}' OFS=_ <<< "$l")"
done < <(find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -name "*_*_*")
```

Comment: Hi,
So I need to define file somehow, right? If I just start by typing "cat file", I get: no such file or directory.

Comment: The data you provided (4 lines) can be stored in any other filename. I just named that file as literal `file`. You can use any other filename also.

Comment: So by combining your answer and the one below, I find that this works:

 ls | tr '' ' ' | awk '{ if ($5=="v2") print $4""$5; else print $4 }'

But this just writes it to the screen. Your solution may change the file names, but I'm not able to run it. It doesn't recognize "file", and if I start by typing cat file, it doesn't accept it.

Comment: You don't need to do `cat file` and don't need any `tr` also. I showed `cat file` as example only.

Comment: When you provided my sample data where did you get it from? It must be in some file right?

Comment: Oh , I see what you mean. 
No, I just did an ls and copied.
The data I provided are not stored in a file, these are the files in a directory. So I need some way to translate this to a command that actually changes the file names.

I could do like this:
ls > file; awk -F_ '$5=="v2"{print $4, $5; next} {print $4}' OFS=_ file > file2

But then I need to merge these two files and add "mv".. If you understand what I mean?

Comment: Come to think of it, I can do like this: 

ls > file.csv; awk -F_ '$5=="v2"{print $4, $5; next} {print $4}' OFS=_ file > file2.csv

Then open the csv files a spreadsheets, add "mv" in a first column and run it as a shell script

Comment: Right it can be done that way but let me suggest you a better way in few minutes by editing my answer.

Comment: @user2886045: See the updated answer above. It will just echo `mv...` commands. Once you are satisfied with mv commands just remove echo from while loop above.

Comment: Thank you! 

There seems to be a problem with this code when I run it. I neglected to mention that these aren't files, but directories. Your code seems to go into the directories and copy or rename files, while leaving the directory names intact.

Comment: You need to place all the info upfront to avoid confusions like this. Anyway I updated my answer, check it out.

Comment: Hats off for your patience.  +1.

Comment: @devnull: Thanks, this +1 is much more valuable than others since it wasn't easy for me to understand what the original problem was.

Comment: @anubhava Yes, it's obvious.  Nobody has even *dared* to format the original post even after a full day has gone by.

Comment: @devnull: Moreover OP started with this line `I have a directory with lots of files with names like this: * _ * _ *` but now those are not files but directories :P

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that unfortunately (or not) uses `awk`:

```
$ ls
FIRSTSTRING_SECONDSTRING_THIRDSTRING_12345
FIRSTSTRING_SECONDSTRING_THIRDSTRING_12345_UNWANTED
FIRSTSTRING_SECONDSTRING_THIRDSTRING_12345_v2

$ ls | tr '_' ' ' | awk '{ if ($5=="v2") print $4"_"$5; else print $4 }'
12345
12345
12345_v2
```

How it works: the `tr` command replaces `_` with a single space; then the little `awk` program tests if the 5th field is the optional `v2`. If it exists, both 4th and 5th are printed with an underline separating them; if not, only the 4th field is printed.

To rename the files:

```
for file in `ls`
do
  mv $file `echo $file | tr '_' ' ' | awk '{ if ($5=="v2") print $4"_"$5; else print $4 }'`;
done
```

Or, in a single line:

```
for file in `ls`; do mv $file `echo $file | tr '_' ' ' | awk '{ if ($5=="v2") print $4"_"$5; else print $4 }'`; done
```

But be careful with destination files with the same name, just like in my example:

```
$ ls
12345 # (one of the '12345' files was overwritten)
12345_v2
```

Regarding the "no awk, please" request, I would like to add that you should use the right tool for the right problem. Otherwise, it would be like driving a screw with a hammer.

Comment: Hi, 
There is a problem with this, in that there is always a $5, whether it is the wanted "_v2" or the unwanted part. So if $5 is _v2. it keeps it, and that's good, but if there is no _v2 it will keep the unwanted part.

Comment: However, this works:

ls | tr '_' ' ' | awk '{ if ($5=="v2") print $4"_"$5; else print $4 }'

Comment: But this just displays it, I don't know how to change the file names.

Comment: Extended the answer to include the instruction to rename the files.